# Installation of updates 2016

Tags: 2013, 2016, 2019

I plan to install updates on SharePoint 2016.
The steps are as follows:

1. Create a backup of the farm and databases;
2. Install updates for SharePoint;
3. Disable the distributed cache service;
4. Disable search service
5. Applying updates using `PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`;
6. After applying the update, I perform the update using the script (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/update-workflow-in-sharepoint-server-2013);
7. Turn all services back;

Which services should I disable before installing updates?
Updates have not been made for a long time. Can I install immediately in 2019 or should I put everything in 2018?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no requirement to stop any service but it is advisable to disable at least search as the installation of the binaries will take long time and that is way to avoid it.
2. You wrote that you are applying the update using PSConfig.exe. Maybe you just made a mental shortcut so sorry to point that out. You first need to install updates using binaries in case of SP2016 you need to install 2 main update and language dependent (even if you use just English you still need to do it) only after you install binaries you apply them using psconfig.

with regards to the language dependant fix:

> "The product group released the February 2019 Cumulative Update for
>   SharePoint Server 2016 product family. Be aware that only a language
>   independent fix was released with February 2019 CU. The latest
>   language dependent fix was released with October 2018 CU."

this is quote from the link below

3. You can install latest CU as they are cumulative there is no need to install in between CUs (usually there are couple of exceptions) 
   Please note that the latest CU for SP2016 has some issues and MS advises not to install it.

[Have look here (Stefan has as well some first rate advise about the update process have read through the links on the bottom of the post)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2019/02/12/february-2019-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/)

I modeled my update process after Sharepoint DSC (Desired State Configuration) and I disable those services:

- IISADMIN
- SPTimer
- IIS

Using this script:

```
        Write-Host "Stopping services"
    try{
        Set-Service -Name "IISADMIN" -StartupType Disabled
        Set-Service -Name "SPTimerV4" -StartupType Disabled

        $iisreset = Start-Process -FilePath "iisreset.exe" `
                                  -ArgumentList "-stop -noforce" `
                                  -Wait `
                                  -PassThru

        $timerSvc = Get-Service -Name "SPTimerV4"
        if($timerSvc.Status -eq "Running")
        {
            $timerSvc.Stop()
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
        Write-host "Something went wrong durin Step 2: stopping of the services"
        Throw
    }
```